# Dense linear ordering without end points.

Tags: order-theory

Let $(L,\prec)$ be dense linear ordering without end points. Show that $(L,\prec)$ is separable if and only if $(L,\prec)$ is order isomorphic to a sub-ordering of the real line $(\mathbb{R}, <).$

I know that if $(L,\prec)$ is separable then $(L,\prec)$ is a countable dense linear order without end points. Then by Baire Category Theorem, there exists a proper Dedekind cut $D \subseteq L$ such that $D$ avoids every $X \in \mathcal F$ where $\mathcal F$ is a countable family of closed nowhere dense subset in $(L,\prec)$. But I do not know how to proceed from here.

Comment: It's not true that if $(L, \prec)$ is separable then $(L, \prec)$ is countable (for instance, $(\mathbb{R}, <)$ is separable, but not countable).

Comment: Which direction of the "if and only if" statement are you stuck on?

Comment: Both directions actually. For the $\Rightarrow$ direction, if $(L,\prec)$ is a separable dense linear ordering without end points, does it satisfy the countable chain condition? Because if it did, then the Dedekind completion of $(L,\prec)$ is isomorphic to the real line $(\mathbb{R}, <)$.

Comment: This is getting things backwards. For a DLOWE, separable implies ccc, but that's a moot point since ccc does not necessarily suffice to make a DLOWE's completion isomorphic to $\mathbb R$ (the Suslin Hypothesis, which is independent of ZFC, is that ccc *does* suffice).  However, one can show it directly from separability: a countable dense subset can be identified with the rationals, and then any other point can be mapped to the least upper bound of the rationals whose preimages are below it.